# Calculate user expense balance

Tags: algorithm

devs,

I need help with my current project. I am building a Python application that tracks expenses for a group of users (Split Wise analog).

You can create "groups" and add users to these groups. A group can have one or more expenses (each expense is a number in USD). The application tracks how much each user paid for each expense.

The application should be able to tell the balance: how much any user owes to any other user based on group expenses (assuming all users should spend an equal amount for summary expenses). I need an algorithm how to calculate the balance.

Let's take a look at a **simplified example**.
Say, we have a "Party" group with 3 users, John, Mary, and Maya.  There are 2 expenses related to the "Party" group: "wine" ($30) and "food" ($60). Users paid:

Expense: "Wine" (30):

- John: 0
- Mary: 0
- Maya: 30

Expense: "Food" (60):

- John: 60
- Mary: 0
- Maya: 0

This means Maya bought all wine for $30 and John bought all food for $60.

let's calculate the balance for the "Party" group.

**Wine expense balance**:
John owes Mary 0
John owes Maya 10
Mary owes John 0
Mary owes Maya 10
Maya owes John -10
Maya owes Mary -10

Hence, each user will spend 10.

**Food Expense balance**:
John owes Mary -20
John owes Maya -20
Mary owes John 20
Mary owes Maya 10
Maya owes John 20
Maya owes Mary 0

Hence, each user will spend 20.

**Total balance for the "Party" group**:
John owes Mary -20
John owes Maya -10
Mary owes John 20
Mary owes Maya 10
Maya owes John 10
Maya owes Mary -10

So the `total spend of the group` = 60 + 30 = 90.
`Each user should spend` 90/3 = 30

John, Mary, and Maya will spend $30 each after:

- Mary pays John 20 and Maya 10,
- Maya pays John 10.

I need an algorithm (ideally a Python code) how to calculate the user balance for the group, sort of:

```
def calculate_balance(group_expenses):
    
    balance = {}

    # Do the math here
    
    return balance


# Test the function with the example data
group_expenses = [
    {"John": 0, "Mary": 0, "Maya": 30},
    {"John": 60, "Mary": 0, "Maya": 0}
]

balance = calculate_balance(group_expenses)
print("John's balance:", balance["John"])  # {Mary: -20, Maya: -10}
print("Mary's balance:", balance["Mary"])  # {John:20, Maya: 10}
print("Maya's balance:", balance["Maya"])  # {John: 10, Mary: -10}
```

Because the example data is super simple and even I was able to sort out results intuitively. But at this point, I can't develop a formula for calculating balance mathematically.

Comment: Why should Mary pay Maya 10, when Maya pays that same 10 to John? Then Mary can just pay that directly to John.

Comment: That is why the problem is not that simple, there can be several valid solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the persons by the total amounts they paid. Then iterate this sorted list from both sides as then you have 2 candidates for a transfer between them. As long as a little-paying person needs to pay more to get even, find a next much-paying person and create a transfer between them to make one of them even. Continue like that until all are even:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def calculate_balance(group_expenses):
    summary = defaultdict(int)
    total = 0
    # aggregate what everyone paid
    for d in group_expenses:
        for name, paid in d.items():
            summary[name] += paid
            total += paid
    # Determine what every one should have paid to be equal
    target = total / len(summary)
    # Sort persons by the amounts they actually paid
    items = list(summary.items())
    items.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    # iterate from both sides to get 2 parties for transfers
    counterparty = reversed(items)
    name2, paid2 = next(counterparty)
    balance = { name: {} for name in summary }
    for i, (name1, paid1) in enumerate(items):
        while paid1 < target:  # This person needs to pay more
            topay = target - paid1
            while paid2 == target:  # Find counter party
                name2, paid2 = next(counterparty)
            toreceive = paid2 - target
            transfer = min(topay, toreceive)  # What can be transferred
            # Register the transfer
            balance[name1][name2] = transfer
            paid1 += transfer
            balance[name2][name1] = -transfer
            paid2 -= transfer
    return balance
```

For your example, this is how it turns out:

```py
group_expenses = [
    {"John": 0, "Mary": 0, "Maya": 30},
    {"John": 60, "Mary": 0, "Maya": 0}
]

balance = calculate_balance(group_expenses)
print("John's balance:", balance["John"])  # {Mary: -30}
print("Mary's balance:", balance["Mary"])  # {John:30}
print("Maya's balance:", balance["Maya"])  # {}
```

Maya had already paid the ideal amount, so she does not have to be involved in any transaction. The settlement can be just between Mary and John.